# Strange Error Javacc Terminal

Tags: java, linux, javacc, compiler-compiler

Here's the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" ParseException: Encountered " <ID> "fibo "" at line 1, column 5.
Was expecting:
    "\u0440\u0430\u0432\u043d\u043e" ...

    at RussianL.generateParseException(RussianL.java:1084)
    at RussianL.jj_consume_token(RussianL.java:966)
    at RussianL.Assignmeth(RussianL.java:223)
    at RussianL.Smeth(RussianL.java:189)
    at RussianL.Lmeth(RussianL.java:151)
    at RussianL.Pmeth(RussianL.java:57)
    at RussianL.Start(RussianL.java:17)
    at RussianL.main(RussianL.java:6)
```

No where have i said that i want to use u0440 etc as my grammer for the code.
I have used actual words

All help appreciated.

Comment: We can't guess at custom code. We don't know what any of those methods in the stack trace do.

Comment: this is a cyrillic character http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0440/index.htm because you are parsing russian. something that looks like `pabho`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly sure that this can be fixed by hand editing the XXXConstants.java file.  Since that will get overwritten every time you run javacc, what you should do is write a script that will replace the funky strings that JavaCC produces with the nice strings that you want. This might amount to simply replacing every ocurrence of "\\u4" with "\u4".